# Find consecutive number of days where a column contains a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's imagine we have a list of employees, where each day we track what their task_list was. We can assign a boolean if that list includes something we call 'critical', in this case let's assume the person asked to lock the door has the 'critical' task.

For this additional responsibility, we want to reward any of the employees who have demonstrated that they are competent enough to manage that task for a given number of days in a row.

I've got this list of critical tasks, and am able to flag them successfully day by day, but am having trouble figuring out how to get our counter applied correctly.

Ideally, it increments for each consecutive day where we find one of the critical tasks within their task_list, and resets to 0 on a day where they do not have a critical task.

Here's an example desired output:

| Employee | Day | Task_List | Critical_Task | Consec_Days_Crit_Task |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom J | 10/1/22 | Sweep, Lock Door* | 1 | 1 |
| Tom J | 10/2/22 | Sweep, Lock Door* | 1 | 2 |
| Tom J | 10/3/22 | Mop, Dishes | 0 | 0 |
| Tom J | 10/4/22 | Sweep, Lock Door* | 1 | 1 |
| Sue B | 10/1/22 | Mop, Dishes | 0 | 0 |
| Sue B | 10/2/22 | Mop, Dishes | 0 | 0 |
| Sue B | 10/3/22 | Sweep, Lock Door* | 1 | 1 |
| Sue B | 10/4/22 | Mop, Dishes | 0 | 0 |

I'm able to get the first 4 columns into a temp table no problem, I've tried using a loop to update those counter values as well as tried to use something like the lag function. Just can't seem to wrap my head around how to write the partition statement I guess.

Any advice?

Comment: The record for Sue B on 10/3, is Critical_Task supposed to be 1?

Comment: 1) Show us sample data - and provide it as DDL+DML so we can copy and paste it 2) show us your current query.

Comment: @PatrickTucci - Fixed that, yes the record should show 1 for Sue B

Comment: @DaleK - Was more so hoping for psuedo-code to solve this sort of general ask if at all possible. If DDL/DML is necessary for something like that, I'll have to get back to this thread later once I've had time to write it out.

In terms of current query, this is again just a simplified situation of a much more complicated data situation. Sharing the full procedural flow used to get to the above will likely cause more confusion than attempting to write some sort of psuedo-code for the above example

Comment: 1) This site is not intended for psuedo-code type answers - its intended for actual answers to technical problems. 2) As per the question guide we need a [mre] which emphasis on minimal i.e. of course we are not wanting to see your entire production code. We require you to build the smallest possible demonstration of the issue you are facing, with example data, and then you translate any answer back to your production situation.

Comment: And it should only take you 5 minutes to type out a couple of create temp tables and insert the data above, just don't expect us to do it for you. Use DBFiddle and then provide the link... you'll have an answer in minutes.

Comment: In addition, frequently when creating a [mre], you will solve your own problem because you gain a better understanding, and be dealing with a simpler form of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, for each employee, you need to identify groups of consecutive rows where `Critical_Task=1` (islands) and groups of consecutive rows where `Critical_Task=0` (gaps). After that, you can use the count window function to count the consecutive rows where `Critical_Task=1` for each employee within the defined groups.

```
SELECT Employee, Day, Task_List, Critical_Task, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Critical_Task=1 THEN Task_List END) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY Employee, grp ORDER BY Day) Consec_Days_Crit_Task
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee ORDER BY Day) -
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Employee,Critical_Task ORDER BY Day) AS grp
  FROM Table_Name
) T
ORDER BY Employee DESC, Day
```

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... AS grp` is used to identify the required groups.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZUEnAXGE).

Comment: Thanks for calling it a gaps and islands problem, gave some helpful reading material. Your solution worked pretty out of box from what I can tell at first review, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can left join back on the same data to identify the maximum date where a non-critical task bounds the current record. It's then just a simple matter of using `DATEDIFF()` functions to calculate the total number of consecutive days since the last 0.

I have used your sample data from the 1st four columns and inserted them into a table variable to be used in the examples below:

```
DECLARE @Data as TABLE (
  Employee varchar(50), 
  Day date, 
  Task_List varchar(50), 
  Critical_Task bit)

INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES ('Tom J', '10/1/22', 'Sweep, Lock Door*', 1)
  ,('Tom J', '10/2/22', 'Sweep, Lock Door*', 1)
  ,('Tom J', '10/3/22', 'Mop, Dishes', 0)
  ,('Tom J', '10/4/22', 'Sweep, Lock Door*', 1)
  ,('Sue B', '10/1/22', 'Mop, Dishes', 0)
  ,('Sue B', '10/2/22', 'Mop, Dishes', 0)
  ,('Sue B', '10/3/22', 'Sweep, Lock Door*', 1)
  ,('Sue B', '10/4/22', 'Mop, Dishes', 0);

SELECT Employee, Day, Task_List, Critical_Task
  , DATEDIFF(day, last_0, Day) as Consec_Days_Crit_Task
FROM (
    SELECT a.*
        , coalesce(max(b.Day), 
            dateadd(day, -1, min(a.Day) over(partition by a.employee))) as last_0
    FROM @Data as a
    LEFT JOIN @Data as b
        ON a.Employee = b.Employee AND b.Critical_Task = 0 AND a.Day >= b.Day
    GROUP BY a.Employee, a.Day, a.Task_List, a.Critical_Task
) as a;
```

Comment: You don't need to explain edits... other than in the reason for the edit, which can be seen in the edit history.